# (Database) Can 2 weak entities form an associative entity?

Tags: entities, associative, weak

Currently I have a situation whereby 2 weak entities form an associative entity (Due to a many-to-many relationship).

**"Project" Strong Entity** consist of

```
projectID (PK), projectName, projectStartDate, projectEndDate
```

**"Task" Weak Entity** consist of a

```
composite primary key projectID (FK,PK) and taskID (PK), taskName,etc
```

**"Resource" Weak Entity** consist of a

```
composite primary key projectID (FK,PK) and resourceID (PK), resourceName, maxUnits, standardRate, costPerUse, etc
```

(resource entity is like manpower/equipments/machineries. However, each resource to each project varies, hence I feel that it cannot be a standalone entity but it has to be a weak entity associated to "Project" entity.)

However, 1 resource can have many tasks in a project, and 1 task can have many resources. Therefore it formed a many-to-many relationship. (between Resource and Task weak entities)

Hence, it has an associative entity called "Assignment" entity.

If I were to map out the "Assignment" table, it would have these attributes:

```
projectID, taskID, resourceID, workCompleted, work, units
```

Afterwhich I'm confused, when I create the SQL structure for "Assignment" table, do i reference projectID from **Task Weak Entity**, or from **Resource Weak Entity**?

Or am I mapping everything incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Well - this will be difficult to actually answer in full, because a lot of it depends on your actual data and datamodel etc.

From what you mention, I would think you need a Resource table that's not associated to the Project, because if it's staff / manpower - one staff member should be able to be associated to multiple projects (I would think) making it a many-to-many association between "Staff" and "Project".

So firstly - I think you would need a table structure like this:

```
Staff/Resource --> ResourceOnProject     <-- Project
Id (PK)        --> ProjectID, ResourceId <-- Id (PK)
```

instead of your existing Resource table.

If this is possible, I think it should help you onwards. 
Depending on information in tasks, you might be able to to the same for that.

But now, you'd should have the possibility to change your Assignment to just hold ResourceId from Staff/Resource without the need of the "double" ProjectId problem you're faced with in your current setup.

So basically:

```
Staff/Resource (Id PK)
Project (Id PK)
ResourceOnProject (ProjectId FK, ResourceId FK)
Task (Id PK, ProjectId FK) 
Assignment (TaskId FK, ProjectId FK, ResourceId FK)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Basically in the Resource table, there are attributes like maxUnits, standardRate, costPerUse. (Resources may include equipments also not just manpower). However, for example Jack has other commitments to other projects, hence his maxUnits (like commitment level) for that particular project is 50% instead of 100%. That's the reason why I needed to link Resource to Project because each resource's commitment level to each project varies.

Comment: Those information can still be put on the association table (ResourcesOnProject). Based on your information here, you will need a basic Staff/Resource table - because "Jack has other commitments". That means your "Assignment" table does not refer the association between "Staff" and "Project" but just "Staff", and thereby it removes your issues with the "double" ProjectId for Assignment

Comment: So does this mean that Resource Table should not be a weak entity to Project, but it should be a strong entity on its own?

Comment: You need a base table containing "Jack" and your other staff/resources. The one I called "Staff/Resource" in my answer. Then you can associate that table with your Project containing the information you need for that association. That's the one you called "Resource" and I called "ResourceOnProject". Your Assignment table would then refer to "Staff/Resource" instead of "ResourceOnProject", as well as your Task, and you no longer have the issue with "double" ProjectID reference in Assignment.